# Excel not keeping formatting in table

Tags: excel, colors, formatting

I currently have the following table [image]

When I attempt to add a row at the top I click on row 4, and then click insert. This gives me the following screenshot[image]

As you can see, all the colors and formatting has kept except the very first cell. While it looks like I have it selected it is actually the default light (or slightly darker light) blue. I even have the option "format same as above" yet this still happens. How could I fix this?

I should also state that there are no rules set for conditional formatting

Comment: try deleting rows 3:5, for instance. Then try the insert again. Sometimes the formatting gets whacky depending on what was done to the sheet previously. Also, try formatting the A3 properly through the menu bar and inserting it again. Fixing it manually once may fix the insertion formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I deleted all the empty rows. Inserted a row. Formatted that row to my liking using the ribbon. Then inserted a row and while all of the formatting kept. The first cell did not.

Comment: yuck, maybe someone else can pick up on this, or if you can post the workbook, I can play with it.

Comment: I wish I could post the work book but it's full of proprietary info. Oh well. I do appreciate the help!

Comment: You can post a dummy copy without the prop. info, or just overwrite the info with dummy data.